# Last column of table getting pushed to next line

Tags: tables

This might be a really basic thing that I am struggling with - I'm trying to create a simple table (outputted from Stata) but the last column gets pushed to the next line repeatedly - removing the last column is the only way it doesn't get pushed. This is the table:

```
Variables & \shortstack{No\\Preference} & \shortstack{Ask\\ORS} & \shortstack{Ask\\antibiotics} & \shortstack{Purchase\\elsewhere} & P-Value \\
Age & 43.1 & 43.2 & 44.8 & 43.1 & 0.410 \\
Male & 0.833 & 0.818 & 0.864 & 0.833 & 0.551 \\
Provider has MBBS & 0.271 & 0.312 & 0.313 & 0.271 & 0.654 \\
Patients per day & 35.2 & 34.0 & 35.1 & 35.2 & 0.349 \\
Diarrhea case per week & 8.48 & 7.49 & 8.46 & 8.48 & 0.570 \\
Years of experience & 16.7 & 17.4 & 18.2 & 16.7 & 0.396 \\
Works at other facility & 0.034 & 0.034 & 0.041 & 0.034 & 0.670 \\
Beds & 2.10 & 2.25 & 2.23 & 2.10 & 0.398 \\
Dispenses medications & 0.461 & 0.378 & 0.388 & 0.461 & 0.059 \\
ORS available at baseline & 0.572 & 0.545 & 0.564 & 0.572 & 0.945 \\
Correct treatment & 0.887 & 0.899 & 0.877 & 0.887 & 0.758 \\
Has electricity & 0.996 & 0.988 & 0.992 & 0.996 & 0.340 \\
Consultation Fee & 79.0 & 84.3 & 86.1 & 79.0 & 0.526 \\
Fee for ORS (if available) & 13.9 & 14.3 & 16.2 & 13.9 & 0.536 \\
```

And this is the code I use to insert it in my document:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
            \toprule
            \input{Tables/table1.tex}
            \\ \bottomrule          % 08 Dec 2021. Add these slashes.
            \addlinespace[.2ex]
            \end{tabular}}
      
      
\end{table}
```

This is what the output ends up looking like:

[image: Last column is offset to next row]

How can I have all my columns in one row? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, help us to help you. Make from your code fragment one small, but complete document which reproduce your problem.  It should start with `\documenclass` end end with ˙\end document}`. In preamble let be loaded only to your problem relevant packages.

Comment: BTW, your table has 6 columns, but you define only 5 ...

Comment: @Zarko's comment about number of columns is the answer.  Change `{lcccc}` to `{lccccc}` and you should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: For future reference, don't ignore the error messages.  Also, don't `\resizebox` a table.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples how can you write your table:

- with use `siunitx` package, which define  `S` columns type where numbers are aligned at decimal points
- with use `c` column, here numbers are centered

In bot case are used `tabular*` table environment and distances between columns are determined by macro `extracolsep`. Using it, the `\resizebox` is not needed anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.3}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{S} }
    \toprule
Variables   & {\makecell{No\\Preference}} 
                & {\makecell{Ask\\ORS}}
                    & {\makecell{Ask\\antibiotics}}
                        & {\makecell{Purchase\\elsewhere}} 
                            & {P-Value}   \\
    \midrule
Age         & 43.1 & 43.2 & 44.8 & 43.1 & 0.410 \\
Male        & 0.833 & 0.818 & 0.864 & 0.833 & 0.551 \\
Provider has MBBS       
            & 0.271 & 0.312 & 0.313 & 0.271 & 0.654 \\
Patients per day       
            & 35.2 & 34.0 & 35.1 & 35.2 & 0.349 \\
Diarrhea case per week  
            & 8.48 & 7.49 & 8.46 & 8.48 & 0.570 \\
Years of experience     
            & 16.7 & 17.4 & 18.2 & 16.7 & 0.396 \\
Works at other facility 
            & 0.034 & 0.034 & 0.041 & 0.034 & 0.670 \\
Beds        & 2.10 & 2.25 & 2.23 & 2.10 & 0.398 \\
Dispenses medications   
            & 0.461 & 0.378 & 0.388 & 0.461 & 0.059 \\
ORS available at baseline 
            & 0.572 & 0.545 & 0.564 & 0.572 & 0.945 \\
Correct treatment 
            & 0.887 & 0.899 & 0.877 & 0.887 & 0.758 \\
Has electricity 
            & 0.996 & 0.988 & 0.992 & 0.996 & 0.340 \\
Consultation Fee 
            & 79.0 & 84.3 & 86.1 & 79.0 & 0.526 \\
Fee for ORS (if available) 
            & 13.9 & 14.3 & 16.2 & 13.9 & 0.536 \\ 
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{c} }
    \toprule
Variables   & \makecell{No\\Preference}
                & \makecell{Ask\\ORS}
                    & \makecell{Ask\\antibiotics}
                        & \makecell{Purchase\\elsewhere}
                            & P-Value   \\
    \midrule
Age         & 43.1 & 43.2 & 44.8 & 43.1 & 0.410 \\
Male        & 0.833 & 0.818 & 0.864 & 0.833 & 0.551 \\
Provider has MBBS
            & 0.271 & 0.312 & 0.313 & 0.271 & 0.654 \\
Patients per day
            & 35.2 & 34.0 & 35.1 & 35.2 & 0.349 \\
Diarrhea case per week
            & 8.48 & 7.49 & 8.46 & 8.48 & 0.570 \\
Years of experience
            & 16.7 & 17.4 & 18.2 & 16.7 & 0.396 \\
Works at other facility
            & 0.034 & 0.034 & 0.041 & 0.034 & 0.670 \\
Beds        & 2.10 & 2.25 & 2.23 & 2.10 & 0.398 \\
Dispenses medications
            & 0.461 & 0.378 & 0.388 & 0.461 & 0.059 \\
ORS available at baseline
            & 0.572 & 0.545 & 0.564 & 0.572 & 0.945 \\
Correct treatment
            & 0.887 & 0.899 & 0.877 & 0.887 & 0.758 \\
Has electricity
            & 0.996 & 0.988 & 0.992 & 0.996 & 0.340 \\
Consultation Fee
            & 79.0 & 84.3 & 86.1 & 79.0 & 0.526 \\
Fee for ORS (if available)
            & 13.9 & 14.3 & 16.2 & 13.9 & 0.536 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page  layout)